# Comparing two-sample statistical test results: Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Anderson-Darling

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, anderson-darling-test

I am not sure how to interpret a given Anderson-Darling criterion as computed from SciPy.  Suppose, for example, I have a Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) statistic of 0.60 and an Anderson-Darling (AD) criterion of 5.69 for the same two-sample distributions.  The critical values array for AD is [0.325 1.226 1.961 2.718 3.752 ] with a significance level of 0.00212182.

I know that the higher the KS statistic is (closer to 1), the larger the difference between the CDFs (for the sample CDF compared with the reference CDF).  However, how do I interpret the AD result for these same two samples?

Comment: Wouldn't the p-value supply the answer to the interpretation question?  It's unclear what you mean by "compare results:" what would be the basis for that?  You might need to provide a specific, narrow null and alternative hypothesis for any comparison to be meaningful and useful.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance here!  As we are using two-sample tests, are any assumptions made on the reference distribution shape for the p-value so determined (i.e., normal)?

Comment: The A-D test has to be adapted for each specific distribution family: see Wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test#Tests_for_other_distributions.  The only assumption needed for the K-S test is that the distributions be continuous.

Comment: @whuber I belive the OP is referring to a two-sample version of the Anderson-Darling which is would be distribution-free for the continuous case. To my recollection, Tony Pettit wrote about it in the mid 70s. .... (Edit- here: Pettitt, A. N. A two-sample Anderson-Darling rank Statistic. Biometrika, 63, 161-168, 1976)

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  I am referring to two-sample version of the Anderson-Darling.  In the p-value that is returned from two-sample AD, is it also 'distribution-free' in how it is determined?

Comment: (I edited the original context above for clarity as requested.)